# Running React project is returning error : Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'public'

Tags: node.js, reactjs

```
node:internal/fs/utils:347
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Akash Bhardwaj\OneDrive\Desktop\react\myapp\ C:'
    at Object.realpathSync (node:fs:2580:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Akash Bhardwaj\OneDrive\Desktop\react\myapp\node_modules\temp-dir\index.js:9:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Akash Bhardwaj\OneDrive\Desktop\react\myapp\node_modules\tempy\index.js:5:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'lstat',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\Akash Bhardwaj\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\react\\myapp\\ C:'
}
```

I was trying to run npm start , but this error showed up
After that i tried to uninstall node.js then again i installed it but nothing worked its still showing same.

Comment: You should remove **node_modules** directory and after that reinstall all packages with **npm i** or **yarn install**. **Note:** this commands should run in root of your project not subdirectory such as **public**.

Comment: Still i am getting same error

Comment: It's about your node version. Check your react version and node compatibility and then reinstall all packages. Maybe it will useful.

Comment: I checked but version are up to  date, can u plz suggest something else